# How do I present my output as a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[CHECK_OUTPUT_HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qUHl.png) 
Currently, the output I am getting is in the string format. I am not sure how to convert that string to a pandas dataframe. 
I am getting 3 different tables in my output. It is in a string format. 
One of the following 2 solutions will work for me:

> Convert that string output to 3 different dataframes. OR
>   Change something in the function so that I get the output as 3 different data frames.

I have tried using RegEx to convert the string output to a dataframe but it won't work in my case since I want my output to be dynamic. It should work if I give another input.

```
def column_ch(self, sample_count=10):
    report = render("header.txt")
    match_stats = []
    match_sample = []
    any_mismatch = False
    for column in self.column_stats:
        if not column["all_match"]:
            any_mismatch = True
            match_stats.append(
                {
                    "Column": column["column"],
                    "{} dtype".format(self.df1_name): column["dtype1"],
                    "{} dtype".format(self.df2_name): column["dtype2"],
                    "# Unequal": column["unequal_cnt"],
                    "Max Diff": column["max_diff"],
                    "# Null Diff": column["null_diff"],
                }
            )
            if column["unequal_cnt"] > 0:
                match_sample.append(
                    self.sample_mismatch(column["column"], sample_count, for_display=True)
                )

    if any_mismatch:
        for sample in match_sample:
            report += sample.to_string()
            report += "\n\n"
            print("type is", type(report))
    return report
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more of context? It's hard to understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: @Valentino Sorry for the bad desc..I'm asking a question here for the first time.
So basically, I want my output as a dataframe. When I return the report function I am getting a string. (in the form of 3 tables as I have attached). 
Need help figuring out a way to convert it into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: what I don't understand is how the input is organized. You show a method of a class, but not the class or the input itself. If you already have a dataframe, return it. Or do some selection / manipulation before and then return it. If you have sparse list or dictionaries, build a dataframe and return it.

Comment: The input are 2 tables loaded from SQL server. The class has some functions which help in comparing these tables. So, the input is not in the form a dataframe. I need to load the data back into SQL server and for that I need to convert it into a dataframe first. 
Let me know if this helps you get a better picture :V

Comment: Not really, sorry. How do you read the data from SQL? pandas has the [read_sql_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html) and [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) functions. You may use them to read your SQL data directly into a dataframe and return it.

Comment: I am using the pyodbc library to read data from the SQL server. So I am using datacompy library to compare my tables. The code I have posted is a slight modification of the .report function in that library. [https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/api/core.html]. The output of this function is a string. I was wondering if I can figure out a way to use this function and convert it to a dataframe.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Yes, is possible, let me write an answer to show how you can do. Just one thing, for future questions (or also this one if you wish to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58123303/edit) it): do not post text as image, copy-paste the text in the question. People will be able to grab your text and write an answer using your input. Easier for them (they do not have to reinvent an input), and more useful for you.

Comment: Yes. I tried to post my output as text. When I tried to copy-paste the output it messed up the table format. 
I am not sure how to keep the table formatting and paste it as a text here. Will try to figure it out using the formatting functions StackOverflow provides.

Comment: post the text, select it and press `{}` in the top bar of the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a string, you can pass your string into a file-like buffer and then read it with [pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) into a dataframe.

Assuming that your string with the dataframe is called `dfstring`, the code would look like this:

```
import io
bufdf = io.StringIO(dfstring)
df = pd.read_csv(bufdf, sep=???)
```

If your string contains multiple dataframes, split it with `split` and use a loop.

```
import io
dflist = []
for sdf in dfstring.split('\n\n'): ##this seems the separator between two dataframes
    bufdf = io.StringIO(sdf)
    dflist.append(pd.read_csv(bufdf, sep=???))
```

Be careful to pass an appropriate `sep` parameter, my `???` means that I am not able to understand what could be a proper parameter. Your field are separated by spaces, so you could use `sep='\s+'`) but I see that you have also spaces which are not meant to be a separator, so this may cause a parsing error.
`sep` accept regex, so to have 2 consecutive spaces as a separator, you could do: `sep='\s\s+'` (this will require an additional parameter `engine='python'`). But again, be sure that you have at least 2 spaces between two consecutive fields.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html) for reference about the `io` module and `StringIO`.
Note that the `io` module exists in python3 but not in python2 (it has another name) but since the latest pandas versions require python3, I guess you are using python3.

Comment: This does make sense. But since I have 3 different tables in that string.. I need to create 3 separate dataframes. How do I create 3 separate dataframes if I pass an appropriate sep parameter? 
Also, is it possible to use the startswith() method somewhere to specify the separation..

Comment: That is not possibile. `read_csv` creates one dataframe. You need to break the string before, pass each segment in the buffer and read the buffer with `read_csv`. I've edit my answer.